# SQL Statement to select duplicate records appearing more than 2 times

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help to get the solution for this condition. I have a table containing records, there is a field sku, in this record i have sku's appearing multiple times.
Table structure is like this 
rid|id|sku|name

rid is auto_increment, where is id is varchar, if any sku is available on table multiple times the record looks like this

```
rid  id  sku     name
---  --  ------  --------------
1    3   rs-123  test product
2    3   rs-123  test product
3    4   rs-125  test product 2
4    4   rs-125  test product 2
5    4   rs-125  test product 2
6    6   rs-126  test product 3
```

I used this sql statement to get records that appears only once

```
SELECT *
FROM test
GROUP BY id
HAVING ( COUNT(id) = 1 )
```

This brings the records that are only added once, so according to above give record only rid 6 is the output

I tried to modify the above code to this to get the result of the records which are added 2 times

```
    SELECT * FROM test 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING ( COUNT(id) = 2 )
```

The result I am getting is of those record which are added 2 times, but the issue is the output is appearing only 1 record like this;

```
rid  id  sku     name
---  --  ------  ------------
1    3   rs-123  test product
```

I need to fetch all rows of record that are added 2 times in the database. Please help

Comment: If the SKU column is supposed to be unique, put a unique constraint on it at minimum — or use the SKU as the primary key and get rid of the `rid` column.  Also, tables have names; not giving the table names is one of the commonest 'errors' in SO questions tagged SQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT t.rid
     , t.id
     , t.sku
     , t.name
  FROM test t
  JOIN ( SELECT s.sku 
           FROM test s 
          GROUP BY s.sku
         HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
       ) d
    ON d.sku = t.sku
```

The inline view aliased as `d` returns the sku values that appear more than once in the table.  We can join the results of that query to the table to get all rows that have a sku that matches.

Are `id` and `sku` interchangeable? That wasn't clear to me.  (If `id` is dependent on `sku` and `sku` is dependent on `id`, then you can replace references to `sku` with references to `id` in that query.

Comment: Worked perfectly fine. Thank alot.

Answer (score 5):

Test Driven Query Design — TDQD — to the fore.

#### Find the SKUs that appear more than once

```
SELECT sku
  FROM test
 GROUP BY sku
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

#### Find the details for all the rows where the SKU appears more than once

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM test AS t
  JOIN (SELECT sku
          FROM test
         GROUP BY sku
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       ) AS s
    ON t.sku = s.sku
```

Comment: This is exactly the way I would do it. Except I would qualify all column references, including the columns in the inline view. I omit the (optional) AS keyword for table aliases, and always include the AS keyword for column aliases. Other than that, I think this query is the same query as in my answer.)

Comment: @spencer7593: yes, it is mostly the same. I guess I was picking up on your brain waves as I was typing—and I'd noticed that our answers were equivalent. I don't always qualify columns in an inner query unless it is a correlated subquery, but that's stylistic, as is the use of `AS`. I'll observe that we periodically get bug reports from people who have problems with `FROM Keyword Keyword` table aliases, but the workaround is `FROM Keyword AS Keyword`, so I head off the trouble at the pass, as it were, by using `AS` all the time. I have to remember to omit it when the question is tagged Oracle.

Comment: @Jonathon: yes, the differences i pointed out are just differences in style. I like the style you use, the leading keywords on each line right aligned, and the closing paren lined up underneath the opening paren... the subquery indented, I think this style makes the statement MUCH easier to read, and MUCH easier to figure out what its doing.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE test
(rid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,id INT NOT NULL
,sku VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES 
(1,3,'rs-123','test product'),
(2,3,'rs-123','test product'),
(3,4,'rs-125','test product 2'),
(4,4,'rs-125','test product 2'),
(5,4,'rs-125','test product 2'),
(6,6,'rs-126','test product 3');

SELECT x.* FROM test x JOIN test y ON y.id = x.id GROUP BY x.rid HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
+-----+----+--------+----------------+
| rid | id | sku    | name           |
+-----+----+--------+----------------+
|   1 |  3 | rs-123 | test product   |
|   2 |  3 | rs-123 | test product   |
|   3 |  4 | rs-125 | test product 2 |
|   4 |  4 | rs-125 | test product 2 |
|   5 |  4 | rs-125 | test product 2 |
+-----+----+--------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

This query should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE 
   id IN(SELECT id FROM test group by id HAVING count(id) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you group by `Id` you can't get more than one Id in the group thus `COUNT(Id)` is always 1. Use this instead

```
SELECT * FROM test 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING ( COUNT(sku) = 2 )
```

If you want to get all records with more than one duplicate `sku` use this:

```
SELECT * FROM test 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING ( COUNT(sku) > 1 )
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM test 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING ( COUNT(sku) > 1 )` won't help.

Comment: Can you explain the phrase "won't help"?

Comment: It doesn't return all the duplicate records.

Comment: Uhm, it is returns `Id` of duplicate record.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan yes it doesn't return all duplicate records, just bringing one row.

Comment: OK. The answer at below just what you want. Good luck!