# Select duplicate records by IN() clause of mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having issue with `IN()` clause in MySQL.

**Query:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_table 
WHERE 1=1 
AND id IN (36,36) 
ORDER BY find_in_set(id, '36,36')
```

Here 36 is my primary key of the table. Now if I run this query then it gives only 1 record. I want 2 records even if they are duplicate.

Also one thing that if `IN (27,34,22,25,22)` then it should be return 5 records and in order it is given.

Please help me out.

Comment: @Parixit..i guess one should not use duplicate values as primary key..

Comment: Your best shot is to handle that in application, because if not, then your issue will upcome to transforming comma-separated string into set of values, which is difficult in MySQL since it has not sequences support

Comment: @Avinash Its not about setting primary key. I am just retrieving data according to my id which I pass to IN() caluse.

Comment: @AlmaDo I dont get your point. But I just got that you want me to do that in my application.

Comment: Point is simple: to handle duplicates, you'll need to join your records with data set, which represents your `IN` clause. And to get that data set - you'll need to split your string into that data set

Comment: @AlmaDo You mean to say that I can not do this without any join. correct?

Comment: Oh, you can use something like subqueries. `JOIN` is just the thing that's designed for such issues

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43922/discussion-between-parixit-and-alma-do)

Comment: I think you are looking for this-

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541307/sql-statement-to-select-duplicate-records-appearing-more-than-2-times

Comment: so you want order of in? '...  and in order it is given.' but what order? do you think of the order it comes from DB File(s)? You should not depend on that, so is there an other field for 'order'?